# CTools Include sometimes doesn't work

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-ctools

So using the drupal include function for a dropdown works, but on certain pages the scripts are not included and there is no error thrown anywhere. This happens inside hook_block_view. On the actual page, Drupal.behaviors.CToolsDropdown is missing on pages it does't work on. But no indication as to why.

```
ctools_include('dropdown.theme');
...
$block['content'] = array(
      '#markup' => theme_ctools_dropdown($vars),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ctools_include()` loaded the `dropdown.theme.inc` file, and we know that because otherwise, invoking `theme_ctools_dropdown()` would result in fatal error due to the call to undefined function.

`theme_ctools_dropdown()` itself unconditionally adds the needed `dropdown.js` and `dropdown.css` files.

So I believe that your code never gets invoked on these pages (i.e the block does not get to be displayed). To prove that, squeeze in a `drupal_set_message('Hello world');` somewhere in your `hook_block_view()` and see what will happen.

If you see the message, search for `hook_js_alter()` in your code, maybe there's a logic somewhere which removes `dropdown.js` on those pages.

*Update:* `drupal_add_js()` called within the block won't be included after clearing caches. So you need to include JS and CSS files using #attached property:

```
ctools_include('dropdown.theme');
// ...
$block['content'] = array(
  '#markup' => theme_ctools_dropdown($vars),
  '#attached' => array(
    'css' => array(
      drupal_get_path('module', 'ctools') . '/css/dropdown.css',
    ),
    'js' => array(
      drupal_get_path('module', 'ctools') . '/js/dropdown.js',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Just tried this. Interestingly it comes up on some pages, but not others still, the dropdown is always displayed, but stuck in the open state because no js. Also no hook_js_alter

Comment: So even more odd behavior, It works the first time after doing flush all caches, then every time after that, the messages do not load, and dropdown is broken.

Comment: Heh, I totally forgot about block caching and css/js inclusion. The amended answer should probably solve your problem.

Comment: Yes it was definitely the cache set in block_info!